# How to auto resize the figure to cover all subplot in Python matplotlib?

Tags: python, scroll, matplotlib, paging, figure

How to auto enlarge the figure size according to the size of subplots?

I have searched many many topics for this problem, but none is helpful.

The basic logic is:

```
fig = plt.figure()
sub_fig_order = 0
for i in range(0, len(Big Varying Num)):
  sub_fig_order += 1
  ax = fig.add_subplot(len(Big Varying Num), 1, sub_fig_order)
pp = PdfPages('multipage.pdf')
plt.savefig(pp, format='pdf')
pp.close()
```

Since the number of subplot is not fixed and the number is large, it is difficult to use `fig.set_size_inches(x, y)` to reserve a reasonable size. How, the subplots are overlapped with each other.

Comment: Why can't you scale the (y-size of the) figure with the number of figures (`set_size_inches(x, N*y)`)? You do know the final number of figures in the end. Or, since you use a multipage PDF for output anyway, why not plot e.g. two figures per page, then move to the next page?

Comment: A similar question was asked here, maybe that is also helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12938568/matplotlib-savefig-into-different-pages-of-a-pdf