# Matplotlib savefig into different pages of a PDF

Tags: python, pdf, pagination, matplotlib

I have a lengthy plot, composed o several horizontal subplots organized into a column.

When I call fig.savefig('what.pdf'), the resulting output file shows all the plots crammed onto a single page.

Question: is there a way to tell savefig to save on any number (possibly automatically determined) of pdf pages?

I'd rather avoid multiple files and then os.system('merge ...'), if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that there is a more elegant way to do this, but one option is to use tempfiles or StringIO to avoid making traditional files on the system and then you can piece those together.

Comment: You can't just concatenate pdf files and expect the result to be a valid pdf file with the constituent pages.

Comment: No, nor did I mean to suggest you could, though I can see how it could be read that way.  But there are a number of tools like pyPdf that let you stitch multiple PDF files together.

Comment: Yes, his answer came in after mine.  I agree that he nailed it.  I'm glad the mention of pyPdf helped.

Answer (score 1):

I was wondering how to perform a similar thing. I have a set plots coming from different image files, which vary depending on the file. So the idea is, once I found a nice number of plots that can be plotted in a page, apply this for the files. Luckly, I found a solution suggested here: http://blog.marmakoide.org/?p=94. However it does not work correctly, since it only plots the first panel plots, leaving the rest of the panels empty. I modified it and here I include a working version for a (1XN) grid and the output plots.

```
import numpy

from matplotlib import pyplot as plot
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

# Generate the data
data = numpy.random.randn(7, 1024)

# The PDF document
pdf_pages = PdfPages('histograms.pdf')

# Generate the pages
nb_plots = data.shape[0]
nb_plots_per_page = 5
nb_pages = int(numpy.ceil(nb_plots / float(nb_plots_per_page)))
grid_size = (nb_plots_per_page, 1)

for i, samples in enumerate(data):
  print
  print i,i % nb_plots_per_page,samples
  # Create a figure instance (ie. a new page) if needed
  if i % nb_plots_per_page == 0:
    print 'Opening'
    fig = plot.figure(figsize=(8.27, 11.69), dpi=100)
  # Close the page if needed
  elif (i + 1) % nb_plots_per_page == 0 or (i + 1) == nb_plots:
    plot.subplot2grid(grid_size, (i % nb_plots_per_page, 0))
    plot.hist(samples, 32, normed=1, facecolor='#808080', alpha=0.75)
    plot.title(str(i+1))

    plot.tight_layout()
    pdf_pages.savefig(fig)
    print 'Closing'
    print i,samples
    # Plot stuffs !
  print i,samples
  plot.subplot2grid(grid_size, (i % nb_plots_per_page, 0))
  plot.hist(samples, 32, normed=1, facecolor='#808080', alpha=0.75)
  plot.title(str(i+1))


# Write the PDF document to the disk
pdf_pages.close()
print 'histograms.pdf'
```

[image: Page1]

[image: Page2]