# Large number of plots in matplotlib subplots

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

I am trying to plot 38 plots using matplotlib.pyplot.subplots but the graphs come out too small and on top of each other.

```
N = np.linspace(3,40,38,dtype=int)

plt.figure(1, figsize=(12,2))

for i in N:
    plt.subplot(38,1,i-2)
    plt.plot(N,i*N)
    plt.subplots_adjust(hspace = 5)
```

How do I modify this code so that I can see the individual plots clearly?

Comment: have you tried `tight_layout()`?

Comment: The question lacks a clear problem statement in the sense that it is not clear what the resulting plot should look like. It sounds a bit like *"I want to write a complete book on one sheet of paper, but I can't distinguish the letters any more, what shall I do?"* Please [edit] the question to be very clear about you desired outcome and the reasons to put 38 graphs on a two inch figure.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12938568/matplotlib-savefig-into-different-pages-of-a-pdf to plot over different pages. You are not saying whether you wish to save the figure on a file or plot runtime with plt.show()